# Swift - How to use integrate SwiftValidator into my project

Tags: ios, forms, swift, validation

I've got a login form which takes 2 alternate forms dependent on how a user taps a segmented control .... either as a register form with email, password, and repeat password; or as a login form with just email and password.

When a user fills out the register or login fields and taps the register/login button ... I log the user in using code along the lines of ...

```
    @IBAction func loginRegisterTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
       //check whether the sender tag is registerTag (in which case a new user is registering or alternately returning user logging in 
       //do various checks and if all good submit the form
}
```

Ive recently copied over a validation library (SwiftValidator) to my project, and configured it to also validate fields when the login/register button is tapped ie i insert the validation code above my own code in the loginRegisterTapped ibaction method. My code after integrating SwiftValidator essentially becomes

```
@IBAction func loginRegisterTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
       //validation
    self.clearErrors()
    validator.validate(self)
       //check whether the sender tag is registerTag (in which case a new user is registering or alternately returning user logging in 
       //do various checks and if all good submit the form
}
```

The SwiftValidator library ends us calling 2 delegate methods (in my LoginViewController) on validation success or failure as follows

```
    // SwiftValidator library Delegate methods
func validationSuccessful() {
    // submit the form
}
func validationFailed(errors:[UITextField:ValidationError]) {
    // turn the fields to red
    for (field, error) in validator.errors {
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        error.errorLabel?.text = error.errorMessage // works if you added labels
        error.errorLabel?.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Given validation is successful, how can i get code to return to my @IBAction func loginRegisterTapped(sender: AnyObject) method and continue with my own form submission code (... I need a reference to the sender to check it's tag to determine whether the button was tapped as a "Register" button or a "Login" button) rather than conducting the form submission as suggested by the SwiftValidator library within it's validationSuccessful delegate method where i dont have access to the sender var. ie what options do i have here or what would be considered best practice? ... I thought of customizing the validationSuccessful method to return perhaps a bool to the calling function but doubt if that's the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, I'd do the successful form submission in the `validationSuccessful()` method, not in your own action method. I'd avoid using tags to differentiate the login and register buttons, and instead have each one call a separate action method. You're not saving any time, code, or logical clarity by handling them both with the same handler.

Comment: thx. I changed my code to reflect what you suggested and seems to be working. I was tagging the login button to determine if it was a register compared to a login but i changed it to be different buttons and i hide or show the buttons dependent on whether user is registering or loggin in. I transferred my form submit logic to the validationSuccessful() method within which I still needed some way to check if its a register or a login ... i did this by querying the validator itself for the number of fields it's validating (3 is register and 2 is login) and my code submits correctly.